# Editar y actualizar en un json node

Tags: nodejs, crud

Tengo un json estoy armando un crud y no me actualiza yo intente de todo  , no se como publicar muy bien aca , es mi primer pregunta , basicamente estoy aprendiendo y tengo que entregar este proyecto en node de una pagina de productos que se pueden aditar ya la tengo armada solo la parte de editar actualizar no me funciona , dejo parte del codigo , no se si se puede subir el proyecto

```
 //el controlador 

editProd: (req, res) => { 

let id = req.params.id
let editProduct = productos.find(producto => producto.id == id)
res.render("edicionProd", { editProduct })
},

update: (req, res) => {
 let id = req.params.id //El id que nos requiere por la url el usuario
 let editProduct = productos.find(producto => producto.id == id) //El producto que se va a 
editar

editProduct = {
    id: editProduct.id,
   ...req.body,
    
    imagen: editProduct.imagen,
    marca: editProduct.marca,
    modelo: editProduct.modelo,
    precio: editProduct.precio
   
}; 
console.log(editProduct.imagen)
console.log(editProduct.marca)
console.log(editProduct.modelo)
console.log(editProduct.precio)

let newProducts = productos.map(producto => {    
                                             
 if (producto.id === editProduct.id) {
    return producto = { ...editProduct };  
        } 
    return producto;            
})
  fs.writeFileSync(productosFilePath, JSON.stringify(newProducts, null, ' '));
     res.redirect("/" + editProduct.id)

console.log(editProduct.marca)
}


 //En router :

 const router = require("express").Router();
 const productoController = require("../controller/productosController");

 router.get('/',productoController.list);
 router.get('/create',productoController.create);
 router.post('/create',productoController.stock);
 router.get("/:id", productoController.detail)
 router.delete('/:id', productoController.destroy)
 router.get('/:id/edit', productoController.editProd)
 router.patch('/:id', productoController.update);

 module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Por favor, puedes explicar con más detalle qué parte de tu código falla? Considera agregar un [mcve]. No es necesario agregar todo el proyecto. Intenta explicar el resultado obtenido y el resultado esperado. Saludos